# Error : INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR in Paypal Android SDK

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating android Paypal SDK in my Android app, here I have got my client id and using in my code, When I start transaction with paypal "Pay with Card" and using 4111 1111 1111 1111 and 5555 5555 5555 4444 but I always getting error message. I could not trace the reason for this, Any suggestion ??

Error Logs :

```
03-30 15:01:17.442    1491-1520/com.example.paypaldemo.app W/E﹕ T SN:14 PayPal-Debug-Id header: 902b48df2f324
03-30 15:01:17.446    1491-1520/com.example.paypaldemo.app E/paypal.sdk﹕ request failure with http statusCode:500,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
03-30 15:01:17.454    1491-1520/com.example.paypaldemo.app E/paypal.sdk﹕ request failed with server response:{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"902b48df2f324"}
03-30 15:01:17.466    1491-1491/com.example.paypaldemo.app E/PayPalService﹕ INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR
03-30 15:01:17.642    1491-1491/com.example.paypaldemo.app W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-30 15:01:18.262    1491-1517/com.example.paypaldemo.app W/E﹕ N SN:16 PayPal-Debug-Id header: 46b25b2a17eff
03-30 15:01:32.874      473-487/system_process D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb910ea88, tid 487
03-30 15:01:33.174      112-280/? W/audio_hw_primary﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 44149 to 23219
```

Code :

```
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.75"), "USD", "hipster jeans",
        PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);

intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Screenshot : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it simply by using my credit card number and Expiration date that was provided by Paypal and it worked !

Comment: Glad you got it working.  There are issues in PayPal sandbox with too many using the same credit card number.  There are ways to get test cc numbers from your sandbox test accounts.

Comment: Please write that card number and expiration  date here